# Cut out transparent circle with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to make this shape in CSS3. Is it possible? :S

[image]

My plan is to put a picture in the background so I want that this part be transparent (that round part )

EDIT:
The biggest problem is that background is not solid color, it is image and background of `div` body must be semi-transparent.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS. However, it's possible with svg.

Answer (score 4):

The cut out circle can be made only with CSS using box-shadows. The following demo has fixed height/widths but it is possible to achive the same output with percent size and therefore make it **responsive** :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ftvaL27b/)**

output :

[image: cut out circle with CSS]

```css
body{
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-640-480-7.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
div{
    width:600px; height:350px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    z-index:1;
}
div:before,div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;    
}
div:before{   
    top:-50px; left:225px;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px #000;
    z-index:-1;
}
div:after{
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 600px -300px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The image has disappeared, can you please upload an image on imgur and use it as a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CSS only version using gradients as background-images.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2JNW/1/)

```
div {
    width: 235px;
    height: 115px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    background-color: #717172;
    background-image: 
        radial-gradient(center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%),
        linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(113,113,114,1) 100%);
    background-size: 128px 128px, 100%, 100%;
    background-position: center -54px, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat
}
```

(skipped vendor prefixes here, but not in the fiddle)

*To the naysayers: CSS matured a lot, just use some imagination. :)*

Comment: the biigist problem is that bg is not solid color, it is image :S and bg of div body must be semi transparent

Comment: You'll want to look into SVGs then. :P It's not CSS only, but definitely a web compatible standard you can build on.

Comment: @vals http://jsfiddle.net/Bruno_AFK/R6Rc9/ i try do modify your code and make somthing i need but now i have all done only one thing, top is not all the way transparent (that circle) can u help?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can only draw the rectangle and add a circle with the same color as the background in order to mimic the effect of a transparent circle. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZtT3/3/):

```html
<div id="box">
    <div id="circle">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {background-color:Purple;}

#box {
    margin:5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    width:10em;
    height:5em;
    background:Black; /* default background */
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, Black, #555);
}

#circle {
    margin-left:3em;
    border-radius:4em;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2em;
    width:4em;
    height:4em;
    background:Purple;
}
```

Change the background color of the `<body>` tag and you will see the whole circle.

Answer (score -4):

I stand Corrected! You CAN create SOME complex shapes using CSS3 only.. Thanks for sharing all the solutions.

Ignore the following:
No, you cannot create complex shapes using just CSS3. You can create them using SVG or HTML5 Canvas. If I understand your question correctly, you just want to add an image with with transparency as a background image? To do that, just create an image with a transparent background (.gif, .png, .svg) and use that. Images with transparent regions can be used with CSS3.