# Put image inside paralelogram without curvature

Tags: html, css, image, transform, skew

I need put images inside paralelograms. I tried use `transform: skewX(45deg)` but itscurvature images. How can i do it write?
My code :

```
<div class="offers-container">
  <div class="red line"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let car of cars|async">
      <div class="car-img-container" [ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: 'url('+car.image_url[0]+')'}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-top red-triangle"></div>
  <div class="right-top black-triangle"></div>
  <div class="left-bottom red-triangle"></div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="red line row">
      <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let car of cars|async">
        <label class="title">
          {{car.make}} {{car.model}} {{car.year}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="black line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-bottom black-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

```
$red: #EA2340;
$black: #062639;

.offers-container {
  height: max-content;
  position: relative;;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.red {
  background: $red !important;
}

.black {
  background: $black !important;
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  .line {
    height: 6vh;
  }
}

.black-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: transparent solid 50px;
  border-bottom: transparent solid 50px;
  border-right: $black solid 50px;
  border-top: $black solid 50px;
}

.red-triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: transparent solid 100px;
  border-bottom: transparent solid 100px;
  border-right: $red solid 100px;
  border-top: $red solid 100px;
}

.right-top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.left-bottom {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.col-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
.car-img-container {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.title {
  font: Bold 32px/38px Bebas Neue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(90%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

My result [image]
Result without `transform:skewX(45deg)`[image]

Comment: To clarify; you want the image view box to trasform rather than the image itself

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like [this can't be done with CSS alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261341/cut-out-transparent-circle-with-css3).

Comment: Yes, I need transform just view box. But I don't find on your link something for this occasion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this provlem, maybe its will be helpfull to somebody
What was changed:
Html

```
 <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let car of cars|async">
      <div class="car-img-container" [ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: 'url('+car.image_url[0]+')'}">
      </div>
    </div>
```

To

```
 <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let car of cars|async">
      <div class="car-img-container">
        <div class="car-image"[ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: 'url('+car.image_url[0]+')'}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.car-img-container {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}
```

To

```
.car-img-container {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.car-image {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: skewX(-45deg) scale(1.6);
}
```

What i receive [image]